# Streaming file from android sdcard to windows host machine

Tags: android, adb

I have a file on the sdcard which is being written to by an app constantly, I need to pull the file from the device as it is being written to by the app, onto my windows host machine for further analysis.

`adb pull` is no good as it pulls the whole file then stops, but of course the file is still being written too. And anyway the file gets very big so i don't want to copy the whole file each time, just the parts that have been written to since i last read it.

`adb shell dd` might be an option but i can only get it to copy from one file on the sdcard to another file on the sdcard, i.e. not my windows machine:

e.g. `adb shell dd if=/sdcard/input.pcm of=/sdcard/output.pcm` then use skip and seek dd options.

if i used dd and a pipe:: `adb shell dd if=/sdcard/input.pcm  > output.pcm` the output file has some corruption: 0x0D, 0x0D is added randomly to the pcm data. Same as if I just do adb shell cat input.pcm.

I also thought about writing the data to logcat and parsing it, but this is rather clunky and messy and there is a ton of data.

Another option might be splitting the file up in to lots of small files as they are being written and then using adb pull.

None of these are ideal. Ideally i'd like a program on the host that can pull the data at my control, e.g fopen, fread, etc. But I am not sure if this is possible.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to fulfill my requirements:

1. Read all the file that's available to windows host
2. Read the parts of the file that have been updated since i last did a read (e.g every 100ms)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your specific requirement, so it doesn't matter to modify the source code of Android.

Why don't you implement another adb command? Then you can record the last read position and use adb newcommand filename to incrementally pull out the file.

The implementation of adb can be divided into two parts: host side, and adbd.

In host side, when you type a command, it goes to `adb_commandline()` in commandline.c.

```
if(!strcmp(argv[0], "pull")) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        return do_sync_pull(argv[1], ".");
    } else if (argc == 3) {
        return do_sync_pull(argv[1], argv[2]);
    } else {
        return usage();
    }
}
```

Then the `do_sync_pull` continously communicate with the adbd. The adbd(adb.c) listens to the request sent from the host side.

A simple approach is to add another argument to the do_sync_pull, and let the adbd continously seek the file and send back the file content.